# How to name value with range of 0.0 to 1.0?

Tags: math, naming

Quite often I use values between 0.0 and 1.0 to hold progress, or transparancy, or other things that can go from **none** to **full**.
A percentage if you will.

I don't want to call it a *percentage* because it is not expressed as a value from 0 to 100.

To give my variables a clear name, I still would like to describe this kind of value.

What would be an appropriate name?

Comment: It is called a fraction

Comment: Percentages are frequently expressed as a decimal value between 0.0 and 1.0.  `percentage` is a perfectly valid name for this type of value.

Comment: Since percentages range from 0 to 100.0, it's confusing to say "percentage" when the range is [0,1].  I say "proportion" in these cases.

Comment: Percent etymologically comes from "per cent": per hundred. Two per cent: two every hundred. It would be etymologically correct to call it "perunit".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is called a [**normalized value**](http://www.fundza.com/vectors/normalize/index.html).

Comment: Normalize is a verb. If a variable is called a `normalizedValue` one might think the value has been scaled down to a 0 to 1 range or even scaled up. Additionally values can be normalized to other ranges like 0 to 100 or 0 to 255.

Comment: The first part of your comment, that describes exactly what I was searching for.
The second part I can agree on, it doesn't say anything about the range. Any suggestions for improvement?

Answer (score 1):

Proportion or portion

--

Credit Matt Timmermans in the comments of the original question

Comment: To me (pro)portion feels like it is being compared to something, and that is not what I intended.

Answer (score 0):

I am partial to call them Zadeh-numbers, in contrast to boolean numbers which can only be 0 or 1, Zadeh studied fuzzy logic and developed rules to deal with logical values in the continuous interval [0-1].

Therefore, Zadeh-numbers or fuzzy-numbers is my proposal.

Comment: This sounds appropriate, however the term 'fuzzy-number' seems to refer to a type of number with a different kind of meaning: 
"A fuzzy number is a generalization of the real numbers, in the sense that it does not refer to one single value but rather to a connected set of possible values with weights." ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_number )
Now, I am not completely sure I understand this definition, but it doesn't seem to match what I had in mind with my question.

Comment: In that case Zadehnian numbers, that name is not used for anything, as far as I know. There are z-numbers, but not Zadehnian.